# Set User Permission for each volume within docker-compose

Tags: docker, shell, docker-compose, dockerfile, devops

This is my docker-compose file, and I have two mounted volumes, and each volume require a different user and group owner

```
version: '3'
services:

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    user: ${USER_ID}:${GROUP_ID}
    volumes:
      - "./storage/etc/mysqld.cnf:/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf"
      - "./storage/var/log/mysql:/var/log/mysql"

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin:5.1.1
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
```

If I'm applying this docker-compose all these volumes will have similar user and group owners
I expect that there is an option to make for each volume a specified user owner

Answer (score 1):

Neither Docker nor Compose has any option to change the ownership of files in volumes or bind-mounted directories.

You mount a file and a directory into the `mysql` container.  These will both have the *numeric* user and group owner they have on the host.  Those numeric IDs may or may not exist in the container's `/etc/passwd` file, but it usually doesn't matter.  There is no way in Docker to change the file ownership, unless your container runs as root and runs **chown**(1) as part of its startup sequence.

If these two things have different ownership, you may need to change this on the host before you launch the container

```sh
sudo chown -R "${USER_ID}" ./storage
```

In practice, given what you show, so long as the `mysqld.cnf` file is readable and the container runs with `$USER_ID` as the owner of the log directory, the container will probably run successfully.